# using the "minus' operation to find if a condition is met

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

ok so i am trying to use pl/sql to find out if there is a presence of a value, or no value. I know i will probably have to use "count", but not sure how or where exactly. this is what i have so far...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Validate_Prereq_Met
AS
(
    p_snum      IN Enrollments.snum%TYPE,
    p_callnum   IN Enrollments.Callnum%TYPE
)
    v_pcnum   VARCHAR2;
    v_cnum    VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
    --classes needed minus classes taken
    SELECT pcnum AS v_pcnum
      FROM prereq
     WHERE cnum IN (SELECT cnum
                      FROM schclasses
                     WHERE callnum = p_callnum)
    MINUS
    SELECT cnum AS v_cnum
      FROM enrollments, schclasses
     WHERE enrollments.callnum = schclasses.callnum AND snum = p_snum;
END;
```

I need this to return nothing (meaning that requirements are met) or return a value ( meaning that requirements not met).

Comment: I don't have oracle instance at hand but you obviously doing something very wrong. `IIF`, `NVL`, `CASE .. END` (at last!) are your friends. And your question is more Oracle SQL than PL/SQL. (PL - is Ada-like constructs: `begin..end`, loops, variable declarations and such)

Comment: @ignaz - the MINUS set operator is a perfectly valid way of solving this problem. Why do you think it is *"very wrong"*?

Answer (score 1):

You got two small typos:

"As" behind parameters. Replaces the "declare" of a plsql-block

VARCHAR has to be defined with a length if it's not a parameter (ex: VARCHAR2(100)). But you want to use NUMBER to calculate something.

#### How to substract values

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Validate_Prereq_Met
(
    p_snum      IN Enrollments.snum%TYPE,
    p_callnum   IN Enrollments.Callnum%TYPE
)
AS
    v_pcnum   NUMBER;
    v_cnum    NUMBER;
    v_result  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    --classes needed minus classes taken
    SELECT pcnum AS v_pcnum
      FROM prereq
     WHERE cnum IN (SELECT cnum
                      FROM schclasses
                     WHERE callnum = p_callnum)

    SELECT cnum AS v_cnum
      FROM enrollments, schclasses
     WHERE enrollments.callnum = schclasses.callnum AND snum = p_snum;

   v_result := v_pcnum - v_cnum;
   dbms_output.put_line('v_result : ' || v_result ); 
END;
```

#### How to make a function with those

If you declare a function you could return your result-value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Validate_Prereq_Met (
    p_snum      IN Enrollments.snum%TYPE,
    p_callnum   IN Enrollments.Callnum%TYPE)
    RETURN NUMBER
AS
    v_pcnum    NUMBER;
    v_cnum     NUMBER;
    v_result   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    --classes needed minus classes taken
    SELECT pcnum AS v_pcnum
      FROM prereq
     WHERE cnum IN (SELECT cnum
                      FROM schclasses
                     WHERE callnum = p_callnum);

    SELECT cnum AS v_cnum
      FROM enrollments, schclasses
     WHERE enrollments.callnum = schclasses.callnum AND snum = p_snum;

    v_result := v_pcnum - v_cnum;
    RETURN v_result;
END;
```

#### You used MINUS

The `MINUS` you are using does not substract values. It is used to substract a set of values from another one.

Example:

We got two Tables - one containing 1,2 and 3 one containing 1 and 3.
Now we can substract the values of table 2 from table 1.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL -- fake-table 1: 1,2,3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 FROM DUAL)
MINUS
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL -- fake-table 2: 1,3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 FROM DUAL)

-- Result: 2
```

Comment: ah, yes. thanks for pointing out those typos! i will use what you gave me here when i get home and see if it helps. Thanks

Comment: MINUS here is a set operation, not subtraction. Ahh.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Correct. Added an example to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a single query using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT pcnum
FROM
   prereq p,
   schclasses schclasses
WHERE p.cnum = s.cnum
 AND s.callnum = p_callnum
 AND NOT EXISTS
 (
    SELECT 'X' from enrollments e
    WHERE e.callnum = s.callnum
    AND e.snum = p_snum
 )
```